# Send WebBrowser Control URL ---> .asmx Service

Tags: vb.net

OK I am brand new to .asmx creation and I am having a hell of a time figuring out to send a URL to .asmx file.  The .asmx file is expecting to receive a parameter named givenURL.

The paremeter givenURL needs to be sent from Windows Forms.

I need to know how I go about doing this?  Do I use SOAP or can I just send it using VB?  I've been playing with this for 2 days now and it is really starting to get to me!  Thanks in advance.  Any help is appreciated.

```
<WebMethod(Description:="Creates PDF Using URL")> _
Public Function CreatePDF(ByVal givenURL As String) As Byte
    Dim theDoc As New Doc
    Dim theID = theDoc.AddImageUrl(givenURL, True, 0, True)

    Do While True
        theDoc.FrameRect()
        If Not theDoc.Chainable(theID) Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage()
        theID = theDoc.AddImageToChain(theID)
    Loop
    theDoc.SaveOptions.Linearize = True

    Dim theData As Byte() = theDoc.GetData()

    Return theData(0)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a reference to your web service in your Windows forms application.

When you reference the web service, Visual Studio will generate a proxy class, abstracting away the complexity involved in generating the SOAP messages and enabling you to deal purely with the proxy object whilst communicating with your web service.

See: [Create Simple Web Service in Visual Studio 2008 / 2010](http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2010/09/create-simple-web-service-in-visual.html)

Comment: I did that already, I just cant seem to find any way to do it with my own head.  I am going to back at it tomorrow and see if I can't break through with something.  All I get is about 6 classes when I try to talk to the web service after adding the reference.  None of them seem to make any sense as of yet.